# Spring+Hibernate config xml database settings

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to use postgresSql database with spring. I always use mysql so I don't have any idea how to make connection setting for it. I am getting some error. Can someone help me with it. Thanks in advance.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<beans profile="default">
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <!-- <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/> -->
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://username:password@host:5432/database"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**Error**

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:428)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy19.listUser(Unknown Source)
    com.spring.app.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1389)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1399)
    org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:63)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:71)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:61)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy19.listUser(Unknown Source)
    com.spring.app.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:71)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:61)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy19.listUser(Unknown Source)
    com.spring.app.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-204-45-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d19is0l4vni97q'
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:71)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:61)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy19.listUser(Unknown Source)
    com.spring.app.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:289)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:71)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:61)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy19.listUser(Unknown Source)
    com.spring.app.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.
```

Comment: Why don't you look at error bit closely and search on the internet? Anyways your connection string is wrong. Try: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=xyz&password=secret&ssl=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the following

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://YOUR_HOST:YOUR_PORT/YOUR_DB_NAME"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: @ Dmytro @Prasad Thank you for answering... I tried with HSQLDB and MySQL both are working fine. Its only giving error with PostgresSql database. Is there any special settings I need to configure to make it work ?

Comment: Working fine. I made a mistake. In PostgresSql  'User' is a reserved keyword so thats why it wasn't giving error.

Answer (score 0):

From your logs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

You have to add the dependency into a pom.xml file in your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```